# Start systemctl service on user login

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I'm trying to create a service that runs at user login.

As a non-root user, I've created a file:

```
> cat ~/.local/share/systemd/user/voodoo.service

[Unit]
Description=User service test

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "touch /tmp/ok123"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But, systemctl does not recognize it,

```
> systemctl --user restart voodoo.service
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to `enable` the service first:

```
systemctl --user enable voodoo.service
Created symlink /home/andreatsh/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/voodoo.service → /home/andreatsh/.local/share/systemd/user/voodoo.service
```

As you can see, this simply create a symlink in the appropriate folder.
Then I run:

```
systemctl --user restart voodoo.service
```

and the service worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Two, actually.  This is the far more probable one.

Ubuntu 15 switched to systemd for system-wide service management.  But per-user service management was still the domain of upstart, and this was still the case in 16.04.

So naturally `systemctl` isn't going to find a per-user instance of `systemd` to talk to.  Note that `systemctl` did *not* say that it didn't recognize the service unit file.  It said that it could not connect to the "bus" through which it talks to the per-user instance of `systemd`.

## Further reading

- https://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/780747/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/844502/43344
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194208/5132